# SQL: selected date is out of range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which returns the latest date when the row was created. The date is '2010-02-03'

```
SELECT * FROM
[LinkedServer].[Server].[Table]
WHERE [TimeStamp]= (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
FROM [LinkedServer].[Server].[Table]
WHERE UserName IN 
(SELECT Tagname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM LocalServer.MyDatabase.dbo."Taglist"
WHERE LOCATION = 'Europe' AND COUNTRY = 'England'))
```

This query works fine however I want to insert an IF ELSE statement, so IF I SELECT a different date, bigger than the MAX(TimeStamp) then to return an error message. The way I tried was the following:

```
IF MAX(TimeStamp) > '2011-02-15'
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM
[LinkedServer].[Server].[Table]
WHERE [TimeStamp]= (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
FROM [LinkedServer].[Server].[Table]
WHERE UserName IN 
(SELECT Tagname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM LocalServer.MyDatabase.dbo."Taglist"
WHERE LOCATION = 'Europe' AND COUNTRY = 'England'))

END
ELSE 
PRINT 'Date out of range'
```

Unfortunately this way the query is not working. Any suggestions on where should I change the code? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @MaxTS datetime

SELECT @MaxTS=MAX(TimeStamp)
FROM [LinkedServer].[Server].[Table]
WHERE UserName IN 
(SELECT Tagname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM LocalServer.MyDatabase.dbo."Taglist"
WHERE LOCATION = 'Europe' AND COUNTRY = 'England')

IF @MaxTS > '20110215'
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM
[LinkedServer].[Server].[Table]
WHERE [TimeStamp]= @MaxTS

END
ELSE 
PRINT 'Date out of range'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm executing the query.As soon as it returns something I will let you know.